# Node.js - Verify that user is in AD group

Tags: node.js, express

So I have a application that I want to check if a user is in a `AD-Group` to be able to access.

I checked out `passport-kerberos` but I could not see how to detect the user's add groups without logging the user in, which he already is on the domain.

On C# .Net solutions we use on IIS this runs just fine, but how can I get this on Node.js with Linux as server not microsoft?